# How does Mediaelement handle missing files?

Tags: mediaelement.js

We are looking for a way to capture when mediaelement does not load a file either because it does not exist (404 error) or the request is never processed (timeout situation).  It does not appear that the error event is called in these situations, is that true?

Any thoughts on how to handle this so some type of recovery can be made?

Answer (score 0):

this probably doesn't answer your whole question, but the following is a simple trick I use to test if the file exists or not:

```
<?php

$mp3_url = "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/mp3.mp3"

/* convert the lecture URI into an absolute path for file_exists() */
$mp3_abs_url = preg_replace( "#" . WP_CONTENT_URL . "#", WP_CONTENT_DIR, $mp3_url );

if ( file_exists($mp3_abs_url) ) {

    echo do_shortcode("[audio mp3=$mp3_url][/audio]");

} else {
    ?>
    <div> <?php echo "No MP3 available."; ?> </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Otherwise the mediaelements just displays a player with 0:00 duration.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using HTML5, you can add a listener to the `error` event for underlying `video` or `audio` element:

```
$('audio').on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Additionally, you may initialize MediaElement in API-way:

```
var player = new MediaElement('player1', {
    // fires when a problem is detected
    error: function () { 
    }
});
```

however, in my experience this function hasn't been executed if resource gives 404.